# Invalid platform error when using wkhtmltopdf in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux, wicked-pdf

I have deployed an app that uses wicked-pdf for PDF generation, but I can't get it to work. My server uses ubuntu-20.04 and below is the error that I get (I use ruby:2.7.1-alpine)

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf:69:in `<main>': Invalid platform, must be running on Ubuntu 16.04/18.04/20.04/22.04, CentOS 6/7/8, Debian 9/10, Archlinux amd64, or Intel-based Cocoa macOS (missing binary: /usr/local/bundle/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf_alpine_3.12.0_amd64). (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following line to dockerfile:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add wkhtmltopdf ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

And updating `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`

```
require "wicked_pdf"

WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

Comment: If you are using the system package for `wkhtmltopdf`, then you no longer need to have `wkhtmltopdf-binary` in your `Gemfile`. All it does is package up a number of binaries for different linux versions and architectures, which don't match your system anyway.